# Is PS3 / PS4 Online Multiplayer Cross-Platform?

Tags: ps3, psn, ps4

So now the PS4 is out... Does anyone know if PS4's and PS3's online multi-player is cross-platform?

For example, can someone playing COD:Ghosts on a PS3 play with someone on COD:Ghosts on a PS4?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[It is possible for PS3/4 games to be Cross-Play](http://www.polygon.com/2013/10/30/5047272/sony-ps3-and-ps4-cross-play-is-technically-possible) but it is not the default. You will have to check whether each specific game supports PS3/4 cross play as it's up to the developer to implement.

Comment: I thought it would be possible seems they'll probably be using the same servers. It's a shame it's not something that's been included... Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

Not at the moment. Maybe the CoD developers can add that feature after patching it, if enough users request it on CoD community.

[Playstation.blog](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2013/10/30/ps4-the-ultimate-faq-north-america/) is your best source, considering it comes directly form playstation

Over here it states that the ability for ps3 and ps4 users to crossplay is available, but it depends on the developers.

> **Q:** Can PS4 and PS3 users play together online, cross-platform?
>
> **A:** The functionality is technically possible and some developers may choose to support it for their titles.

Answer (score 1):

If you go on ps store you will see that there are downloads that allow you to play cross platform its under ps3/ps4

Comment: Is that so? That's pretty cool! Is it game-specific or one generic download that can be applied to all games? Do you have a screenshot or link to any more details? Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't (for COD at least).

Comment: Is that a fact? If so that really sucks... The PS4 isn't out in the UK yet, and whether or not COD is compatible across both consoles online, really affects my decision of getting one... Thanks for posting.

Comment: Yes, it is a fact. Some games will, as Ben notes, have this. I think the only example I've seen so far is DC Universe Online. COD certainly doesn't, and the number of players in multiplayer is different for each version (12 on current gen, more on next).